# Modx how to change /manager/ to /admin/ url?

Tags: php, html, modx, modx-revolution

I've changed the paths in `/core/config/config.inc.php`:

```
if (!defined('MODX_MANAGER_PATH')) {
    $modx_manager_path= '/var/www/mysite/data/www/mysite/admin/';
    $modx_manager_url= '/admin/';
    define('MODX_MANAGER_PATH', $modx_manager_path);
    define('MODX_MANAGER_URL', $modx_manager_url);
}
```

but when I go to /admin/ - it gives me error 'page can't be showed'

the path /manager/ - collides with the ispmanager path....any help please

Comment: If you setup simple index.html page, what is the path of that page? Does it look like this: `/var/www/mysite/data/www/mysite/index.html`?

Comment: did you rename /manager/ folder?

Comment: Make sure the path `/var/www/mysite/data/www/mysite/admin/` is readable by the webserver (filesystem permission).

Comment: Try to clean the directory: `/var/www/mysite/data/www/mysite/core/cache`